# decimal to octal conversion in c programming (using code blocks)

Tags: c

Decimal to octal conversion c.using code blocks 16.01.the conversion works until 63.This is my first time posting here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
// conversion of decimal to octal
int main()
{
    int num,sum,count,x,y;
    printf("enter a number\t");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    count = 0;
    sum = 0;
    while (num>0){
        x=num%8;
        x=x*pow(10,count);
        count=count+1;
        num=num/8;
        sum=sum+x;
    }
    printf("\n%d",sum);





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect time to lean how to use a debugger, and how to use it to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: i found out it is working in Dev c++ but i prefer writing codein code blocks

Comment: what happens at 64? It seems to be working just fine when I tested your code.

Comment: it comes out to be 99.BTW what ide are you using?

Comment: @Davidjones floating poitns are weird :P but it comes out to 100 using gcc 32bit, gcc 64bit, clang, and visual c++

Comment: Please edit your question to include the input that causes the wrong output, together with the actual and *expected* output. Then remember that [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) is a *floating point* function, with all the problems that includes.

Comment: @Davidjones I just installed codeblocks 64bit ... let me test it out ...

Comment: Thanks for going through the trouble of installing code blocks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i don't get your point

Comment: @Davidjones I figured out what's wrong with your code LOL, it's so silly hahah I should've had my coffee first

Comment: Floating point arithmetic will lead to rounding errors. What if your `pow` call returns `49.999999` instead of `50.0`? That will result in wrong result in your multiplication and more importantly ***truncations*** when converting the result of your multiplication to an integer.

Comment: that is exactly what is happening instead of 1  pow gives .99

Comment: Thanks a lot @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    // conversion of decimal to octal
    int main()
    {
        int num,i,len=0,x[100];
        printf("enter a number\t");
        scanf("%d",&num);

        while (num>0){
            x[len]=num%8;
            num=num/8;
            len++;
        }
        for(i=len;i>=0;i--)
            printf("\n%d",x[i]);
        return 0;
   }
```

This will work for the conversion from decimal to octal.

Note: Check the logic works!.Make the sum `long int`. After 63 your `int` no longer able to hold the answer.

Comment: Thanks but can if you can point out the bug in my code i will appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is actually reported by the compiler if you turn on some warnings, however the problem is that you are implicitly converting from `double` to `int`, and depending on the implementation, you'd lose precision. `pow` returns a `double` but you're storing it in an `int` (`x`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
// conversion of decimal to octal
int main()
{
    int num,sum,count,x,y;
    printf("enter a number\t");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    count = 0;
    sum = 0;
    while (num>0){
        x=num%8;
        x=x*pow(10,count);
       /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ problem here */
        count=count+1;
        num=num/8;
        sum=sum+x;
    }
    printf("\n%d",sum);





    return 0;
}
```

## now the fix

Instead of using the library pow, you should implement your own that's integer only (because you KNOW you are using ints only)

```
/* a trivial implementation */
long pow10(int  n) {

      long result = 1;
      while(n--) {
          result *= 10;
      }
      return result;
}
```

Now to clean up the program a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

long pow10(int  n);

/* a trivial implementation */
long pow10(int  n) {

    long result = 1;
    while(n--) {
          result *= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int num, count;
    long sum, x;
    printf("enter a number\t");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    count = 0;
    sum = 0;
    while (num>0){
        x=num%8;
        x=x*pow10(count);
        count=count+1;
        num=num/8;
        sum=sum+x;
    }
    printf("\n%ld",sum);
    return 0;
}
```